# Access Power BI API using managed identities

Tags: powerbi

I'm struggling to find good examples on how to use Managed Identities to access Power BI Admin API using Power BI cmdlets. Lots of examples using Az cmdlets.

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId [tenantid] -Credential [???]

It works well with other service principals (using app registration) but I fail to find examples that uses managed identity and Power BI PowerShell. Is it supported?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is yet supported. Take a look at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status

Comment: One can use a Managed Identity to make Power BI REST calls: https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2022/04/refresh-power-bi-datasets-with-adf-or.html

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to use a user assigned managed id with PowerBI SDK using the following:

Set up your managed id according to the article linked in the comments of another answer,by joining your managed id to the security group that can access PowerBI API. [Refresh Power BI Datasets with ADF or Synapse (MSI)](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2022/04/refresh-power-bi-datasets-with-adf-or.html)

In my code I then create a `PowerBIClient` using the following:

```
    var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    var accessToken = tokenCredential.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default" })).Token;
    var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken, "Bearer");
    _powerBIClient = new PowerBIClient(tokenCredentials);
```

This is working for me.